# jquery update hidden and a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, not the greatest with jQuery but know enough to get by. I created this mock up that is base on my application and wanted to see if there is a better way to update hidden values and a tags. When the form is saved I am using the sortorder to find the corresponding .ui-sortable li that has a tag and hidden fields to get updated on the page. I am trying to update the correct one and looping all of them checking with the sortorder  I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do this?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/vh9n5srL/35/
```

actual code from a project

```
$("#submit-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sortOrder = $(this).data('sortorder');
        $('.ui-sortable li').each(function (i) {
        if (i == sortOrder) {
            console.log('Updating');

            $("#References_0_UI").html(data.referenceText);
            $("#References_0_UI").attr("href", data.GuidelineExternalReference);

            $('input[name="References[0].Text"]').val(data.referenceText);
            $('input[name="References[0].Link"]').val(data.GuidelineExternalReference);
            $('input[name="References[0].GuidelineId"]').val(data.Value);
            console.log("Completed Task");
        }
});
```

Comment: `I created this mock up` You're around long enough to know [actual code from a project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard A mock up is still an actual project. The code doesn't look like it's psudocode or has sections of it missing with some nice comment like `// Do my project`. There are various places on Meta where producing a mock up is suggested by previous moderators and high rep users. Is there actually any context missing from the above code or are you just triggered over some minor words?

Comment: (@Peilonrayz triggered by `this […] is base on my application` -  bee-holder, anyone?)

Comment: @greybeard That's been recommended on meta.

Comment: I updated with the actual code from a project not sure how that helps

Comment: It makes it a concrete example of working code.

Comment: In the code in your question, the `$("#References_0_UI").html` and similar lines look like they wouldn't work, since the index is being hard-coded. Did you mean `$('References_'+ sortOrder + '_UI').html` like in the fiddle?  Also, I don't understand the purpose of iterating over the `.ui-sortable li`s, since the found `li` is never used. (The `li` isn't in any of the code I see either)

Comment: Yes still working out the application part to this. I guess there is no need to loop all the li.

Comment: @certainperformane is there a better way to set the values for all the hidden fields?

Comment: @greybeard the UI to close should contain a button to retract the VTC - see [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/341145) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *main* issue I see is that the looping doesn't accomplish anything useful, since you never reference the `li` that you iterate over - just take the `sortOrder` from the form and concatenate it into the selectors you try to find.

Because you reference the `#References_##_UI` twice, consider saving it in a variable first - or, even better, since this is jQuery, you can chain methods on the selected collection.

It sounds like the `data.referenceText` is *text*, not HTML markup - in which case you should insert it into the DOM with `.text`, not with `.html`. (`.text` is faster and safer)

```
$('#submit-form').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const sortOrder = $(this).data('sortorder');
  $(`#References_${sortOrder}_UI`)
    .text(data.referenceText)
    .prop('href', data.GuidelineExternalReference);
  $(`input[name='References[${sortOrder}].Text']`).val(data.referenceText);
  $(`input[name='References[${sortOrder}].Link']`).val(data.GuidelineExternalReference);
  $(`input[name='References[${sortOrder}].GuidelineId']`).val(data.Value);
});
```

The above looks *mostly* reasonable to me, but I'd change the HTML too, if that's permitted. Numeric-indexed IDs are never a good idea; IDs should be reserved for singular, unique elements. (You can also consider not using IDs at all, because every time there is one, a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) is created, and globals can result in confusing behavior).

A related issue is that the submit handler here is attached to:

```
$('#submit-form').submit(
```

Since IDs must be unique in a document, this will only attach a listener to a single form, but it sounds like you have multiple forms that you want to listen for `submit` events to.

To solve the duplicate IDs and the numeric-indexed IDs, use the already-existing class to select the forms instead, and once you have a reference to the form in the handler, use `.find` to select its children elements that need to be populated.

Your 3 hidden inputs are somewhat repetitive. It might look somewhat tolerable now, but if you might add more, or for the general case of linking each data property name to a particular input, consider using an object or array linking each property to the selector:

```
const inputNamesByDataProps = {
  referenceText: 'Text',
  GuidelineExternalReference: 'Link',
  Value: 'GuidelineId',
};
$('.form-horizontal').on('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.find('a')
    .text(data.referenceText)
    .prop('href', data.GuidelineExternalReference);
  for (const [dataProp, inputName] of Object.entries(inputNamesByDataProps)) {
    $this.find(`input[name$=${inputName}]`).val(data[dataProp]);
  }
});
```

(The `[name$=${inputName}]` means: "Find an element whose `name` attribute ends with what's in `inputName`")

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-sortorder="1">
  <p>Update Values</p>
  <a class="References_1_UI" href="www.current.com" target="_blank">Testing html</a>.
  <input type='hidden' name='References[1].Index' value="1">
  <input type='hidden' name='References[1].Link' value="www.oldlink.com">
  <input type='hidden' name='References[1].Id' value="88">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The input HTML name attributes look pretty repetitive too, but repetitive HTML *usually* isn't something to worry about, especially if your backend logic is easier to work with when the attributes are like `References[1].Index`. But if you wanted, you could change it to something like

```
<input type='hidden' name='sortorder' value="1">
<input type='hidden' name='Index' value="1">
<input type='hidden' name='Link' value="www.oldlink.com">
<input type='hidden' name='Id' value="88">
```

putting the `[1]` into the hidden `sortorder` input instead, and then parse the form values on the backend.

Comment: is this the correct format  (`#References_${sortOrder}_UI`) I am getting an error.

Comment: Yes, that's valid syntax, see https://jsfiddle.net/61z4u7jc/ - that's a template literal, which is more readable than concatenation IMO. If your environment doesn't support ES2015, you should strongly consider upgrading - that was an eternity ago in web development terms.